# placeholder(input) onclick effect in CSS3

Tags: css, onclick, placeholder

I have styled a placeholder like this:

[image]

It shows like this on click:

[image]

But i want it like this:

[image]

```css
#input-id {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
}

#input-id:checked {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<input id="input-id">
```

Comment: Hello, could you please check my edit and also add the relevant html code?

Comment: :checked is not avalaible for input which are not radio or checkboxes. Use either `:focus , :active` or just `input` with the rule : `outline:none;` .

Comment: You want to show two dots on the input field when clicked/focused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pu `outline: none;` on `focus` :

```css
input {  
  border:none;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
}
input:focus{
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 2px black solid;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

For more information about `:focus` selector and `outline` property, see the following documentations: [:focus selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp) and [outline property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You can remove this by using

```
#input_id:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```